# Array Formula Conditional Count

Tags: excel, count, formula

I have a worksheet containing some names in column A, and some country names in cells B1:E1 (USA, France, China, Brazil). The number of times a name has visited each country is listed in the relevant cells - so for example 'Mark Johnson' in A20 can have 8 in B20, 1 in C20, 0 in D20 and 13 in E20.

I would like to create an array formula that calculates how many names have been to at least 2 countries more than 5 times, how many have been to at least 3 countries 8 times etc. However I'm finding it a bit of a challenge to get this right.

The roundabout method I've employed is to create additional columns with a regular `COUNTIF` and `COUNTA` formulae - in other words, I count the number of countries a name has visited more than X times (`COUNTIF`) and then use the `COUNTA` to sum the number of names in that column who have visited X times. The problem with this is that I need to add a fair number of additional columns, each one corresponding to a different X (i.e. number of times that the countries have been visited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will count the number of rows that have a number >= 5 at least twice, change the 2 and 5 accordingly

`=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((B2:E10>=5)+0,{1;1;1;1})>=2)+0)`

The {1;1;1;1} denotes 4 columns - change as required if you have a different number of columns or you can automate that part using this "array formula" version

`=SUM((MMULT((B2:E10>=5)+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:E1)^0))>=2)+0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

...or another option is to use `FREQUENCY` function, e.g. with this "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:E10>=5,ROW(B2:E10)),ROW(B2:E10))>=2,1))`

That should give you the same results as the previous formulas

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been trying to modify the formula to allow for a number between 5 and 8 using: `=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((AND(B2:E10>=5,B2:E10<=8))+0,{1;1;1;1})>=2)+0)`. However I seem to get a #VALUE! error - have I gone wrong?

Comment: AND doesn't work in these type of formulas because it returns a single result rather than the required array. You can use * (multiplication) to simulate "AND", like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((B2:E10>=5)*(B2:E10<=8),{1;1;1;1})>=2)+0)`

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying using the formulas (L), displayed in my example below, with values in K on sample data F:J isn't sufficient.

You're really after what's in F5 in one stab, not what's in K5 after multiple formulas right?

[image]

Or is what I have done in K2:K5 acceptable?

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed the current method I've employed (detailed, although perhaps not too clearly, in the 3rd paragraph above). However as you note I am looking to do this in one stab.

Comment: To be clear, the challenge with using the K2:K5 method is that I would have to repeat this in columns L, M, N etc for each number of times a country is visited. I would like to see several metrics at once in this dashboard - e.g. # times visited more than 2 countries 5x, # times visited more than 3 countries 5x, # times visited 2 countries 10x etc. Given the number of combinations I am interested in, this adds ever more columns to the data and is less flexible than a single array formula.